# When is a problem strongly NP-complete

Tags: np-complete

Let the problem of the diophantic equation 0/1 be as follows.

Input : A polynomial equation on n variables whose coefficients are integers (ex : $2x^3_1 x_2 + x_1x^3_3 - 3x_4 = 8$)

Question: Does this equation have a solution in space {0,1}$^n$ ? (can we satisfy the equation by choosing for each variable the value 0 or 1?)

1 - How to prove that this diophantine equation 0/1 is NP-complete?

2 - How to prove that this diophantine equation 0/1 is Strongly NP-complete (ie its restriction to the case where all the coefficients are bounded by a polynomial of the number of variables is already NP-complete)

Comment: What does it mean for a diophantine equation to be NP-complete? NP-completeness is a category of decision problems. What decision problem do you have in mind?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, NP complete is good for me! but this is a strongly NP complete. How demonstrated that this problem is strongly NP complete.

Comment: As @YuvalFilmus said, It makes no sense to say that "**this** diophantine equation is strongly NP-complete" because 1) you did not specify what decision problem you are interested in, and 2) (strong) NP-completeness only makes sense over classes of instances. The answer to any single (fixed) instance of any problem in NP can be found in constant time.

Comment: Okay, it's true what you said. I formulate the problem:
Input: A polynomial equation on n variables whose coefficients are integers (example: $2x^3_1 x_2 + x_1x^3_3 - 3x_4 = 8$)
Question: Does this equation have a solution in space {0,1}$^n$ (Can we satisfy the equation by choosing for each variable the value 0 or 1) How to prove that this diophantine equation 0/1 is strongly NP-complete?

Comment: @tala again, *this* instance has a fixed answer (we might not know it, but that is besides the point). Nothing to "compute", a simple look up. "Complexity" refers to the resources needed to compute answers to problems with infinite instances (if finite, a boring lookup is all what is needed).

Comment: Thank you for all your comments, now I have reformulated my question. I'm still waiting for your idea

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/121745/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3586812/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is strongly NP-complete; it is straightforward to reduce 3SAT to this problem.

The clause $C = (x_1 \lor \neg x_2 \lor x_3)$ can be encoded as the polynomial $p(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots) = [(1-x_1)x_2(1-x_3)]^2$.  The conjunction of clauses $\varphi = C_1 \land \dots \land C_m$ can be encoded as $q(x_1,\dots,x_n) = p_1(x_1,\dots,x_n) \cdots p_m(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, where $p_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is the encoding of clause $C_i$.  Then, the polynomial $q(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ has a solution in $\{0,1\}^n$ if and only if the original formula $\varphi$ is satisfiable.

Comment: Thank you for your response, the 3-SAT reduction is also the idea I had before. Thanks for this example. Here therefore you have demonstrated question 2 that this is a problem is strongly NP-complete. Can we still use this same approach for question 1 which asks to demonstrate that the problem is NP-complete. I would also like to know the difference between NP-complete and strongly NP-complete in this case.

Comment: @tala, I suggest reading about the definition of NP-completeness and strongly NP-complete.  You might need to ask a different question to learn about those concepts.  Once you do, you should be able to answer that question yourself.